# how to cut a line after @ string and add backslash

Tags: linux

I am trying to cut after excluding @ string and put / slash  at the end of the line without touching if line does not include @ sign.

search and find in the file;

```
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user@yahoo.com/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user@yahoo.co.uk/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user2@yahoo.com/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user@hotmail.co.uk/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user@abc.xxx.co.uk/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user5/
```

what i want to convert like ;

```
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user@yahoo/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user@yahoo2/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user2@yahoo/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user@hotmail/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user@abc/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user5/
```

Comment: Where is the `yahoo2` coming from? Also, try to explain with more detail what you want: remove from `.` once `@` is found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed '/@/ s|\(@[^.]*\).*$|\1/|' YourFile
```

Starting from end instead of `@` (posix version)

#### Explanation

- `/@/`  treat only lines with `@` inside (others stay as they are).
- use `s` action of sed (substitute). Due to char `/` in pattern, I use another separator `|` here.
- `\(@[^.]*\)` means first group of char starting by `@` and following until first dot (in fact all following attached char I can take but not a dot). If there is no dot, it takes all the following content of the line.
- `.*$` means any char after the precedent pattern (our group) until the end `$`.
- this is replaced by content of group `1` (there is only 1 group here) `\1` followed by `/`.

Comment: Very good approach, +1. It would be also handy to add some explanation for future visitors.

Comment: modify the post with more comment, you are right. A bit RAW earlier

Comment: so how to issue this for only specific line number if i know exactly where it is such as for line 25th ? Thanks,

Comment: replace `/@/ ` by `25 ` at starting of sed command telling 'do it on line 25' instead of 'do it on any line with @'

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r 's/@([^\.\/]+)(.*)/@\1\//' < file
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user@yahoo/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user@yahoo/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user2@yahoo/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user@hotmail/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user@abc/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user5/
```

If you want to have more complex handling of the replacement (yahoo vs yahoo2), you will have to use some programming language, IMHO